# individual background colour of options in <select> based on map

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to set an individual background colour of each option of a `<select>` with Javascript. The option text and colour (hex) are stored in a `Map`:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erik_stengel/adqv8zgh/#&togetherjs=qD3ltFg0hx)

```
const map = new Map();
map.set("005", "#886da8");
map.set("0075", "#ffc3cf");

for (const [key, value] of map.entries()) {
  console.log(key, value);
  $('#cmbExample').append($('<option>', { 
        value: key,
        text : key 
    }));
}
```

Finally it should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You just have to set the `style` attribute with a `background` property using the `value`.
[Templating literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) is helpful here.

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set("005", "#886da8");
map.set("0075", "#ffc3cf");
map.set("01", "#ef9b00");
map.set("015", "#2bb430");
map.set("02", "#f7dc01");
map.set("025", "#bc65a2");
map.set("03", "#487ebf");
map.set("04", "#e00124");
map.set("05", "#b36634");
map.set("06", "#949494");
map.set("08", "#ffffff");
map.set("10", "#000000");
map.set("12", "#4bbbd0");
map.set("16", "#8b6d9f");
map.set("20", "#8ccff4");

for (const [key, value] of map.entries()) {
  // console.log(key, value);
  $('#cmbExample').append($('<option>', {
    value: key,
    text: key,
    style: `background: ${value}` // Set the style like this
  }));
}


// Select element
let coulouredSelect = document.querySelector("#cmbExample")

// change event callback
setSelectColor = function(){
  let value = coulouredSelect.value
  coulouredSelect.style.backgroundColor = coulouredSelect.querySelector(`option[value='${value}']`).style.background
}

// change event listener
coulouredSelect.addEventListener("change", setSelectColor)

// on page load
setSelectColor()
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <select id="cmbExample" class="form-select mt-3">

      </select>
    </form>
  </div>




  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How can I change the background colour of the selected option, too? Is it possible to colour the options also on mobile devices?

Comment: I edited a little... For mobile, that is another story. I am not equiped with devices to test that.

Comment: unfortunately still not working for me...

Comment: After appending "Color" in the last line of setSelectColor() it´s working!